# cv2 with Gstreamer. ERROR: GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:716:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element xxx

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp

I have successfully bult opencv with Gstreamer but cannot run a simple test programm with reading a rtsp videoflow and writing frames into a new one.

---

**cmake build flags:** gotten from https://medium.com/@galaktyk01/how-to-build-opencv-with-gstreamer-b11668fa09c p.s all libs are also were installed

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") \
    -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
    -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
    -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
    -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

---

**code snippet:** with free working rtsp camera

```
import cv2
import sys


gst = "rtspsrc location=rtsp://170.93.143.139/rtplive/470011e600ef003a004ee33696235daa latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink"
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(gst)
if video_capture.isOpened() == False:
    print("VideoCapture Failed!")
    sys.exit(1)
```

---

**cv2 built information**

```
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
    GStreamer:                   
      base:                      YES (ver 1.8.3)
      video:                     YES (ver 1.8.3)
      app:                       YES (ver 1.8.3)
      riff:                      YES (ver 1.8.3)
      pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.8.3)
    libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
    gPhoto2:                     NO
```

---

**error with gst logging enabled** with export GST_DEBUG=2

```
python3 test.py
    0:00:00.010455708  1392      0x2674e10 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:716:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "omxh264dec"
    0:00:00.010472883  1----------------------392      0x2674e10 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:801:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no sink [source=@0x267f3e0]
    0:00:00.010722031  1392      0x2674e10 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:801:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no source [sink=@0x2689390]
    0:00:01.579497450  1392 0x7ff6a002f450 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2948:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc0> error: Internal data flow error.
    0:00:01.579576046  1392 0x7ff6a002f450 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2948:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc0> error: streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
    0:00:01.580609562  1392      0x25fdb70 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5483:gst_rtspsrc_try_send:<rtspsrc0> send interrupted
    0:00:01.580704628  1392      0x25fdb70 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7552:gst_rtspsrc_pause:<rtspsrc0> PAUSE interrupted
    OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
    ) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /opencv-3.4.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 890
    VIDEOIO(cvCreateCapture_GStreamer (CV_CAP_GSTREAMER_FILE, filename)): raised OpenCV exception:

    /opencv-3.4.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:890: error: (-2) GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
     in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer
```

Comment: Just try run `gst-inspect-1.0 omxh264dec` - and most possible you will see `omxh264dec` just don't installed on the system.

Comment: @RSATom Thanks for the help, omx is not installed and I cannot install it in any way for ubuntu 18.04. It can be installed on ubuntu 18.04 or it's only for raspberry pi?

Comment: I've seen mention of this module only in context of use it with RPi. So maybe yes, it require RPi to run. Or, maybe, at least something that supports OpenMax.